# Fetching array of array in react js from JSON response

Tags: reactjs

Actually i am fetching data from an API every thing is working quite well but when i fetch array of array then its giving error of undefined..How should i solve this.Any help will be appreciated..Thanks in advance..

This is the response i am getting from an api..

```
{data: Array(10), meta: {…}}
data: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
meta: {message: "Rider's list fetched successfully.", page: 1, per_page: 10, total: 134}
__proto__: Object
```

And i wanted to fetch `total` from the '`meta`'..I have stored response in state called `data` ..And when i put `console.log(this.state.data.meta.total)` its giving me error like:-`Cannot read property 'total' of undefined`

Comment: check in api call response first, are you getting data

Comment: yes i am getting data..See  i have wrote response..above..

Comment: @tarzenchugh I am storing whole response in state called data..So my data  state has two objects called  data and meta....so know how can i access total from meta..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atin Singh answer will work, though it does take the full response object.

Have a look at [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull only the values you want. 
If you want to store them in a single variable, all you need to do is add them to an object. When it comes to state though, the flatter the better.

```js
const {data, meta: {total}} = response;
setState({data: {data, total});
```

You can now access the total with `this.state.data.total`

**Note**: You might want to change the name of the state property data to something else, otherwise you'll have to access it like `this.state.data.data` which is weird...

Or rename the returned data array to something more descriptive than just `data`. For example, if its an array of people, you could do something like:

```js
const {data: people, meta: {total}} = response
setState({data: {people, total});

// this.state.data.people = [{...}, {...}, {...}]
// this.state.data.total = 134
```

Remember, [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so don't just console out after setting the state as this might give you a false negative

Comment: sorry for asking this silly question but where should i write const?? cause i ll get my response from fetch function.. please help..

Comment: Not a silly question at all. Add that const right before you set the state. All you are really doing here is pulling the data you are looking for into new variables.
So depending on how you are using fetch, something like this might work 
`fetch("apiAddress").then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
const {data: people, meta: {total}} = response;
setState({data: {people, total});
`
Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Best of luck with the rest of your app

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this

`state = {data:[], meta:{}}`

after fetching do

`this.setState({data: response.data, response.meta}) //if you are using class that is//`

Considering that object is stored in response variable.. then access it like.

`console.log(this.state.meta.total)`

Tell me if this works.

Edit: Using only one variable --

```
state = {res: {}}
this.setState({res: response})
//access total//
console.log(this.state.res.meta.total)
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept this as an answer and close this question. Cheers!

Comment: But can i make it possible using only one state variable??

Comment: this will work if you want to use only one variable.. tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: okay.. can you console.log `this.state.res`? Do it inside render and before return.

Comment: Please note @AtinSingh, marking the answer as accepted does NOT close the question. Unless it is a duplicate, or is off-topic, you shouldn't mention to users that the question should be closed.

Comment: @Dodiyarutu can u add your console.log in the post